# Core plot Bar Graph delegate methods not getting called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graph, core-plot

I have been facing this problem and I have searched high and low and couldn't find any solution.The Bar plot delegate method `(void) - barPlot:barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:`
is not getting called after tapping on any bar.

In the `GrpahView.m` I have set the `plot.delegate=self` and in `GraphView.h` I have added these `<CPTBarPlotDelegate>`..

I have also set the `plotSpace.allowsUserInteractionEnabled = YES.`
Still no luck.

Please give me a suggestion. My graph is getting plotted on a View that is a subView of another view.

Comment: Please be more explanative about your question. What is GraphView.h? What is barPlot ... so on and so forth. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent view is passing touch events on to the graph hosting view.